# Find orphan nodes with SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I am trying to find orphan nodes (nodes which do not have any incoming relations)  with SPARQL in a Fuseki database.
I tried several queries which all do not return correct results.

I tried the following:

**Query 1 (got this from linkedIn)**

```
  select ?o ?isOrphan where {  GRAPH <http://localhost:8080/catalog/-1305288727> {
      ?s ?p ?o .
      FILTER(!isLiteral(?o))
    bind(!(EXISTS {?o ?p1 ?o2}) as ?isOrphan)}}
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT ?source ?s ?p ?o
WHERE { GRAPH <http://localhost:8080/catalog/-1305288727>{
    ?s ?p ?o  .
    FILTER EXISTS {?source ?p ?s  } .
 }
}
```

**Query 3 - unbound variable pp in FILTER**

```
  SELECT ?source ?s ?p ?o
WHERE { GRAPH <http://localhost:8080/catalog/-1305288727>{
    ?s ?p ?o  .
    FILTER EXISTS {?source ?pp ?s  } .
 }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query finds each entity that is the subject of any triple, and then checks that this entity is not the object of any triple.

```
SELECT ?orphan
FROM <http://localhost:8080/catalog/-1305288727>
WHERE {

  ?orphan ?p1 [] .

  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?linkingNode ?p2 ?orphan . }

}
```